# Android how to clearing touch events between activitie and dialog

Tags: android

Scenario:

There is an activity and a dialog.The Activity has a button to launch that shows the Dialog on screen.

Problem:

when Dialog the is showing and I touch the button (instead of single tap), Dialog becomes invisible but quickly shows up again ! I want to touch outside of the dialog but do not show The dialog again.

How can this be done? Or is there another fix ?

here is my Activity

```
public class MyAndroidAppActivity extends Activity {

Button button;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {

           CallDialog call = new CallDialog();
           call.show(this);

        }

    });

 }
```

}

And my Dialog

```
public class CallDialog{

Dialog mDialog;

public void show(Context context){

 Dialog mDoialog = new Dialog(context);
 setContentView(R.layout.dialog);

Window window = this.getWindow();
window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);

window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH,
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH);

getWindow().getDecorView().getRootView().setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener(){
    @Override
    public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {

    if(event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_OUTSIDE){  

    mDialog.dismiss();

    }

    return false;
   }           
});
```

}
   }

Answer (score 0):

There seems no need to set touch listener for root view, you can control the same thing by invoke setCanceledOnTouchOutside();

```
 /**
 * Sets whether this dialog is canceled when touched outside the window's
 * bounds. If setting to true, the dialog is set to be cancelable if not
 * already set.
 * 
 * @param cancel Whether the dialog should be canceled when touched outside
 *            the window.
 */
public void setCanceledOnTouchOutside(boolean cancel) {
    if (cancel && !mCancelable) {
        mCancelable = true;
    }

    mWindow.setCloseOnTouchOutside(cancel);
}
```

And it's default set false so it can dismiss when touch outside the dialog .

Comment: How to cacth event click outside of dialog

Comment: By default the touch event outside dialog can be consumed if setCanceledOnTouchOutside(true), you can listen to the dismiss event by public void setOnDismissListener(final OnDismissListener listener)